# "wrong number of arguments" with Letter_opener/mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailer

I can't figure out why my 2nd simple_form using letter opener...

My code is as below:

***estimations_controller.rb***

```
class EstimationsController < ApplicationController
  def create@estimation = Estimation.new(estimation_params)
    if @estimation.save
      EstimationMailer.request(@estimation).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'estimations/new'
    end
  end
end
```

***estimation_mailer.rb***

```
class EstimationMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def request(estimation)
    @estimation = estimation
   mail(
      to:      "name@example.com",
    )
  end
end
```

***request.html.erb***

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      Hello,
      Yo got new message from <%= "#{@estimation.first_name}" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I finally got error message as:

" ArgumentError at /estimations
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)"

on the file:
**app/mailers/estimation_mailer.rb**

Whereas, when i use "raise" in this page, @estimation is present..

It is very strange: I set up mailer/letter_opener for an other form on the website, and it is working perfectly. For this 2nd one,I can't find my mistake...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Never use REQUEST as model.... Simple like this!!!!